# How to split the hierarchy in parent child columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, parent-child, hierarchical-data

Input String : pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+', 1, level) as folder_name,
  4         --
  5         case when level = 1 then null
  6              else substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/', 1, level - 1))
  7         end path,
  8         level - 1 as lvl
  9  from test
 10  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '/') + 1
 11  order by level desc;

FOLDER_NAME                                PATH                                                                                        LVL
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----
folder1                                    pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/     4
CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration  pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/                                               3
10600551 - Track Replacement               pcmdocs/Marquette/                                                                            2
Marquette                                  pcmdocs/                                                                                      1
pcmdocs                                                                                                                                  0

SQL>
```

---

If there's a leading `/` (as you commented), code is even simpler:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '/pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+', 1, level) as folder_name,
  4         substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/', 1, level))path,
  5         level - 1 as lvl
  6  from test
  7  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '/')
  8  order by level desc;

FOLDER_NAME                                PATH                                                                                        LVL
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----
folder1                                    /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/    4
CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration  /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/                                              3
10600551 - Track Replacement               /pcmdocs/Marquette/                                                                           2
Marquette                                  /pcmdocs/                                                                                     1
pcmdocs                                    /                                                                                             0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank for the solution it worked well.. but one thing I missed in the input string is / as the first character.  Actual Input String: /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1. the above query is failing to process this. Can you please provide solution for this too??

Comment: Edited; have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions) and a recursive query:

```sql
WITH data ( path ) AS (
  SELECT '/' || 'pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1' FROM DUAL
),
paths ( path, subpath, depth ) AS (
  SELECT path,
         SUBSTR(path, 1, INSTR(path, '/', 1, 1)),
         1
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT path,
         CASE INSTR(path, '/', 1, depth + 1)
         WHEN 0
         THEN path
         ELSE SUBSTR(path, 1, INSTR(path, '/', 1, depth + 1))
         END,
         depth + 1
  FROM   paths
  WHERE  INSTR(path, '/', 1, depth) > 0
)
SELECT subpath
FROM   paths;
```

Which outputs:

| SUBPATH |
| --- |
| / |
| /pcmdocs/ |
| /pcmdocs/Marquette/ |
| /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/ |
| /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/ |
| /pcmdocs/Marquette/10600551 - Track Replacement/CDA-Contract Documentation-Administration/folder1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GzOYL3W1)